Why is どこの used in his sentence?
けれどこの圧倒的な存在感、隙の無さ、そして後ろ暗いところがないすっきりとした明るさは、文字通り"天才剣士"である稲嶺なのだった。
The sentence seems to be saying that the feeling of presence was everywhere and there were no openings. But then why is どこの used here? Doesn't it mean where?

It actually divides into けれど and この, not どこの.
